# Usar comboboxes para listar cidades e bairros

Tags: php, sql, ajax, combobox

Eu quero que os usuários selecionem a cidade e o bairro onde estão e em seguida a cidade e o bairro para onde querem ir através de 4 comboboxes. Os dados estão sendo puxados do banco, e as 2 comboboxes do "Estou em:" estão funcionando, mas as do "Quero ir para:" não.

Print do que acontece: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq8ta.png

Print da base de dados: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Qqf.png

**index.php**:

```
    <body>
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' ) ;
        mysql_select_db( 'fretadoaqui', $con );
    ?>

Estou em</br>
    <label for="cod_cidades">Cidade:</label>
    <select name="cod_cidades" id="cod_cidades">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php

            $sql = "SELECT cod_cidades, nome
                    FROM cidades
                    ORDER BY nome";
            $res = mysql_query( $sql );

            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['cod_cidades'].'">'.(utf8_encode($row['nome'])).'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <label for="cod_bairros">Bairro/região:</label>
    <span class="carregando">Carregando...</span>
    <select name="cod_bairros" id="cod_bairros">
        <option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>
    </select>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('jquery', '1.3');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#cod_cidades').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() ) {
                $('#cod_bairros').hide();
                $('.carregando').show();
                $.getJSON('bairros.ajax.php?search=',{cod_cidades: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                    var options = '<option value=""></option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_bairros + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                    }
                    $('#cod_bairros').html(options).show();
                    $('.carregando').hide();
                });
} else {
                $('#cod_bairros').html('<option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</br>Quero ir para</br>
    <label for="cod_cidades2">Cidade:</label>
    <select name="cod_cidades2" id="cod_cidades2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT cod_cidades, nome
                    FROM cidades
                    ORDER BY nome";
            $res = mysql_query( $sql );
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['cod_cidades2'].'">'.(utf8_encode($row['nome'])).'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>

    <label for="cod_bairros2">Bairro/região:</label>
    <span class="carregando">Carregando...</span>
    <select name="cod_bairros2" id="cod_bairros2">
        <option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>
    </select>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('jquery', '1.3');
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#cod_cidades2').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() ) {
                $('#cod_bairros2').hide();
                $('.carregando').show();
                $.getJSON('bairros2.ajax.php?search=',{cod_cidades2: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(l){
                    var options = '<option value=""></option>';
                    for (var i = 0; j < l.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_bairros2 + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                    }
                    $('#cod_bairros2').html(options).show();
                    $('.carregando').hide();
                });

} else {
                $('#cod_bairros2').html('<option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

**bairros.ajax.php**:

```
<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
header( 'Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"', true );

$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' ) ;
mysql_select_db( 'fretadoaqui', $con );

$cod_cidades = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] );

$bairros = array();

$sql = "SELECT cod_bairros, nome
        FROM bairros
        WHERE cidades_cod_cidades=$cod_cidades
        ORDER BY nome";
$res = mysql_query( $sql );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    $bairros[] = array(
        'cod_bairros'   => $row['cod_bairros'],
        'nome'          => (utf8_encode($row['nome'])),
    );
}

echo( json_encode( $bairros ) );
```

**bairros2.ajax.php**:

```
<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
header( 'Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"', true );

$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' ) ;
mysql_select_db( 'fretadoaqui', $con );

$cod_cidades2 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades2'] );

$bairros = array();

$sql = "SELECT cod_bairros, nome
        FROM bairros
        WHERE cidades_cod_cidades=$cod_cidades2
        ORDER BY nome";
$res = mysql_query( $sql );
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    $bairros[] = array(
        'cod_bairros2'  => $row['cod_bairros2'],
        'nome'          => (utf8_encode($row['nome'])),
    );
}

echo( json_encode( $bairros ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No arquivo bairros2.ajax.php nas linhas:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    $bairros[] = array(
        'cod_bairros2'  => $row['cod_bairros2'],
        'nome'          => (utf8_encode($row['nome'])),
        );
}
```

Você está informando a coluna $row['cod_bairros2'] que não existe, o nome da coluna é cod_bairros. Logo o correto seria:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) {
    $bairros[] = array(
        'cod_bairros2'  => **$row['cod_bairros']**,
        'nome'          => (utf8_encode($row['nome'])),
        );
}
```

Aproveite e revise todas os nomes alterados no segundo arquivo. No entanto o arquivo a ser requisitado pode ser o mesmo nos dois casos. Adicione no final do formulário o seu código jquery alterando somente os IDS. Da seguinte forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#cod_cidades').change(function(){
       consultaBairros($(this), $("#cod_bairros"));
    });
    $('#cod_cidades2').change(function(){
       consultaBairros($(this), $("#cod_bairros2"));
    });
});

function consultaBairros(cod_cidades, comboBairros){
    if( cod_cidades.val() ) {
        comboBairros.hide();
        $('.carregando').show();
        $.getJSON('bairros.ajax.php?search=',{cod_cidades: cod_cidades.val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
            var options = '<option value=""></option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].cod_bairros + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
            }
            comboBairros.html(options).show();
            $('.carregando').hide();
        });
    } else {
        comboBairros.html('<option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>');
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Assim você chama a função e apenas direciona o destino do retorno da consulta.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigada, me ajudou bastante!